# Linux but not windows? Java swing

Tags: java, linux, windows, swing, noclassdeffounderror

So I wrote this program in Linux and it runs perfectly when I create a jar and run it.

But for some reason when I put this jar in windows it doesnt.

Some of it works but when I try to do a simple click action event it crashes and tells me

there is   an

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EVentQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: miginfocom/layout/cc
```

Well anyway I got rid of certain components of it and it works but with them it doesnt.

```
// MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx");
            JPanel content = new JPanel(/*layout*/);

 /*CC componentConstraints = new CC();
            CC c = new CC();
            componentConstraints.alignX("center").spanX();
            c.alignX("center").span();
            c.alignY("bottom").span();*/

            content.add(label/*, componentConstraints*/);
            content.add(label1/*,c*/);

    //  after this I add it to a Jframe etc
```

Everything there that is commented out is the reason it wouldnt work on windows.

But it would on Linux, I have no idea why this is...

Can anyone tell why this is or where to find out. It would be much appreciated and useful for the future :)

Comment: When you bills your project, you are probably have other library jars associated with it, these library jars need to be included within the class path for the application to work. Take a look at [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for more details

Answer (score 5):

I assume your classpath is not correct.
So the required libs (e.g MigLayout) cannot be found.
Windows uses different Path-Seperator (in classpath) than Linux.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that :)

Comment: check your classpath. Windows uses ; (semicolon) as path seperator, linux uses : (colon). further, check if the jars are valid windows path. (e.g /home/user/libs/MigLayout.jar) can be problematic in windows environment

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create an "uberjar" if you expect to distribute just one JAR file and have everything working. On your dev machine you probably have access to your JAR's dependencies, but not so when you copy just the application JAR to Windows.

Comment: *"You would have to create an "uberjar""*  No you don't.  It will work if the LAF is on the run-time class-path of the app.  Making an all inclusive Jar is just one way (and not an especially optimal way) to achieve that.

Comment: MigLayout is not LAF.

Comment: My bad on the API use identification.  But whatever else, it needs to be on the class-path.

Comment: The easiest way to get everything on the classpath is an uberjar.

Comment: How about an edit from *"You would have to.."* to *"The easiest way is to.."* (and related tweaks later in the sentence)?  ***That*** I could agree with.

Comment: You'll jave to pardon my ignorance,  but I can't think of a way to package all classes and their dependencies into a single jar file without ending up with something we would call an uberjar.

Comment: Java Web Start is the 'one click' installer for desktop apps.  It's multiple files, as needed, but the user doesn't have to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for the general tip, but JWS is not a way to package all classes into a single JAR file (which is what my "only way" applies to). Additionally it requires a server to host the files, and access to public Internet on each user site. Those are very far from user-invisible requirements.